# Can I use option like ''format painter'' in Libre Office Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

I used to use 'Format Painter' in office programs of windows, but now I decided to use Libre office calc on ubuntu distribution and I don't see any similar buttons for that operation ...

The main problem is that I need to repeatedly do the same action to format cells in spreadsheets, it would be much easier to do it with format painter or something similar.

Is that possible in Libre Office Calc?

Answer (score 1):

the "Format Painter" exists in LibreOffice Calc:

[image]

and it works exactly like the Windows one.

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice help page](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Copying_Attributes_With_the_Format_Paintbrush) is very, very well documented. All you have to do is to use the search box:

> You can use the Format Paintbrush tool to copy formatting from a text
> selection or from an object and apply the formatting to another text
> selection or object.
>
> In Calc, the Format Paintbrush only
> applies to cell formatting.
>
> 1. Select the text or object whose formatting
>    you want to copy.
> 2. On the **Standard Bar**, click the **Format Paintbrush**
>    icon. The cursor changes to a paint bucket.
>
>    If you want to apply the
>    formatting to more than one selection, double-click the **Format
>    Paintbrush** icon. After you apply all the formatting, click the
>    icon again.
> 3. Select or click the text or object that you want to apply
>    the formatting to.
>
>    By default only the character formatting is
>    copied ; to include paragraph formatting, hold down Ctrl when you
>    click. To copy only the paragraph formatting, hold down Ctrl+Shift
>    when you click.
>
> The paragraph formats are the formats applied to the
> whole paragraph. The character formats are those applied to a portion
> of the paragraph. For example, if you apply the bold format to a whole
> paragraph the bold format is a paragraph format. Then if you unbold a
> portion of this paragraph, the bold format is still a paragraph format
> but the portion you unbold has a "not bold" character format.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Word I used format painter almost all the time.
Now in Ubuntu I use clone formatting in LibreOffice Writer

format painter = clone formatting